# ¿Como obtener valores seleccionados en un ListBox ASP MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Saludos, tengo un inconveniente con mi codigo en Asp Mvc 5, tengo varios modelos relacionados y tengo un Listbox que filtra los valores de un foreign key, pero cuando intento guardarlo solo se guarda un solo valor no todos los seleccionados, y eso ultimoes lo que necesito.

Este es mi codigo,
La clase Estudiante.cs

```
 public class Estudiante
{

   public int EstudianteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
   public string nombre {  get; set; }


  public virtual int MateriaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Materia Materia { get; set; }

}
```

La clase Materia, Materia.cs

```
 public class Materia
{

   public int MateriaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Asignatura")]
   public string asignatura {  get; set; }



    public virtual ICollection<Estudiante> Estudiantes { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProfesorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Profesor Profesor { get; set; }


}
```

la clase Profesor.cs,

```
 public class Profesor
{

 public int ProfesorId { get; set; }
    [Required]

    [Display(Name="Profesor")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Materia> Materias { get; set; }


}
```

Y el listbox en la accion Create, Create.cshtml.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MateriaId, "Materias", htmlAttributes:     new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("MateriaId",ViewBag.MateriaId as MultiSelectList,new { Multiple="multiple", size = "10"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MateriaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

en el controlador, EstudiantesController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EstudianteId,matricula,nombre,apellido,fecha,MateriaId")] Estudiante estudiante)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Estudiantes.Add(estudiante);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //get profesor name



        ViewBag.MateriaId = new SelectList(db.Materias, "MateriaId", "asignatura", estudiante.MateriaId);

        return View(estudiante);
    }
```

y en el index

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var estudiantes = db.Estudiantes.Include(e => e.Materia).Distinct().ToList();



        return View(estudiantes.ToList());
    }
```

Lo que necesito es que el listbox guarde todos los elementos en vez de uno solo.
Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad del modelo donde se guardarían los valores seleccionados en el `ListBox`, que según veo es `MateriaId` y es de tipo `int`, debe ser de tipo `IEnumerable<int>`, para que pueda almacenar más de un valor, pues en una propiedad `int` solo se puede almacenar un solo valor. 

Si de casualidad no puedes cambiar `MateriaId`, puedes crear otra propiedad en tu modelo para esto.
Saludos.